# Tracking add to cart in magento

Tags: google-analytics, magento-1.9, event-tracking

I am trying to find the file in Magento where I can put this code:

```
onSubmit=”_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','addtobasket','Product name','SKU1234',Price]);”
```

Suggestion is on the add to cart button, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Could you said us which template are you using?

Comment: I am using a magento template you can find on www.geboo.nl.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml`.  It maintains buttons "Add to cart" on products pages.

Should you need to edit buttons inside the cart area please see `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`.

Please refer to https://web-experiment.info/articles/cat/faq/post/faq_button_cart for more detail.